# Disable class pointer increment/decrement operators

Tags: c++, pointers, unary-operator

For example code:

```
A* pA = new A;
```

I need to avoid pointer increment/decrement operators during compilation phase:

```
pA++; // MUST failed during compilation phase
```

Comment: That would suck for the implementation of `strlen()`, which is quite possibly an inline function and included in most files you'll be compiling.

Comment: @MSalters OP asked only pointers to A, strlen(A*) is not provided anyway.

Comment: So what would I do if I create an array of `A`'s and want to iterate over it?

Answer (score 2):

You could declare pA as

```
A * const pA = new A;
```

This makes pA a const pointer to an A object. The pointer cannot be changed after initialisation, but the contents of it can.

compare

```
const A *pA = new A;
```

which is a pointer to a const A object.

If you want to iterate over an array of A objects get a separate pointer.

```
A * const pAs = new A[size];

for (A * iter = pAs; iter < pAs+size; ++iter)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to do.

Since I guess you want to do that to avoid unintended errors, I guess smart(ass) solutions do not apply (including inventing some pointer-like wrapper classes etc) because they will increase the probability of errors :)

Comment: >> Since I guess you want to do that to avoid unintended errors.       Yes thats right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with raw pointers, it's impossible.

You need to wrap it with a class that doesn't implement that operators (aka smart pointers).